# remove '/' from RestControllers's RequestMapping in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, url, uri

I'm using spring-boot to wrtie a simple code that is too common to misunderstand.

> I want to show users like `@user1`|`@imAuser` | etc

so I declared an File with following context:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/@")
public class Users {
   @GetMapping("{name}")
   public String user(@PathVariable String name){
      return name;
   }
}
```

But problem is here: I *cannot* access `/@{name}` and i must use `/@/{name}` instead. It's a problem for me.

When I interesting on web and stackoverflow, I found some questions and answers

- on web I find some site that uses "URI filtering". I don't want that! simple as possible!
- I'm not in production step. I use `mvn spring-boot:run` to run spring boot so I don't have `web.xml` and other Tomcat resources. I have just one `pom.xml`
- Don't suggest use `/@/{user}` or use `@GetMapping("/@{name}")` instead. I know what's substitutes! It's my question!

Moreover:

> If you know this question please tell me, let me say better: my question is summarized in below question:
> Why spring-boot add `/` at end of each @xMapping (includes @RequestMapping) and **How to prevent it**?

Comment: Its added because it is additive so the top-level and method-level are merged and considered to be 2 separated parts of the path and thus require an additional `/`. It isn't a simple string concat that is being done.

Comment: Thank you @M.Deinum. But can I remove it?